# Title bug for character "problem"?

Tags: support, title

I tried to create a question before any I notice that was some possible bug here. Why i cannot use character "problem", but others can ? is this bug ? or any mistake make by me ?

[image: Error :]

Comment: @AlE. I am asking why other can use but I cannot

Comment: Grandfathering. Who cares? I don't like the ban on that word, but *choose another one*.

Comment: Those questions pre-date the inclusion of the filter. In fact, if you go to edit one of those questions you won't be able to save it because  of the title, even if you didn't change it. Moderators aren't subject to this of course.

Comment: People. Quit the downvoting. Some poor user has been unable to include a word in their question title that is in other question titles, because stupid word filter. *That's no reason to downvote.*